# Close Modal when clicked outside of it

Tags: react-native

I have created a Modal in which there are two buttons based on the button click the Modal will be closed but I also want to close the Modal when clicked outside of it, how can I achieve this?

Comment: Have a try with using the npm https://github.com/react-native-modal/react-native-modal for more features such as hide modal on the outside press of modal. Set the onBackDropPress props and close the modal on the event.

Answer (score 5):

You can add TouchableOpacity like this and control with state ;

```
<Modal
  visible={isDialogVisible}
  onRequestClose={() => {
  }}>
    <TouchableOpacity
      style={{flex:1}}
      onPress={() => {
        setIsDialogVisible(false)
      }}>
     {.....your code.....}
   </TouchableOpacity>
 </Modal
```

Comment: I want to close Modal when I click outside that Modal.

Comment: Add trancparency={true} to the modal and add this style for TouchableOpacity {
        flex: 1,
        width: '100%',
        height: '100%',
        flexDirection: 'column',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
        backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.62)'
    }

Answer (score 1):

`onBackdropPress` prop will help you to get that;

```
<Modal
  isVisible={isModalVisible}
  onBackdropPress={() => setModalVisible(false)}>
  <View style={{flex: 1}}>
    <Text>I am the modal content!</Text>
  </View>
</Modal>
```

More details [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-modal)

**EDIT**

Got a downvote today so just checked this answer which i posted nearly 2 years ago.

The above answer is for react-native-modal package.

For modal from react native;

To close the modal on backdroppress, we can use a view inside the modal and use the `onTouchEnd` prop on the view and use the closing function there;

```
const [visible, setVisible] = useState(true)

<Modal visible={visible}>
  <View onTouchEnd={() => setVisible(false)}>

    ...Your content inside the modal
  </View>
</Modal>
```

But there is a problem with this approach (I don't know the solution for that, sorry), the modal will close when we click the view or anything inside the view.

EDIT!!
If you utilize Pressable instead of View and use onPress in the place of onTouchEnd, you would be able to access the content in the View to a good extent as such:

```
<Modal visible={visible}>
  <Pressable onPress={() => setVisible(false)}>

    ...Your content inside the modal
  </Pressable>
</Modal>
```

Comment: I am using Modal from react-native

Comment: my answer is for the same

Comment: I am using Modal from 'react-native' not from 'react-native-modal', onBackdropPress is not working on Modal imported from 'react-native'